# Cannot prevent a file from direct URL Access in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm trying to block my direct pdf url but unfortunately my pdfs are accessible directly from the url. I have already edit my htaccess file in which is stored in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`

And my pfds are stored in `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs`

I have gone through these urls:

- [Wordpress protect file if not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547210/wordpress-protect-file-if-not-logged-in)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in

````
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(pdf)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-content/download.php?file=$1 [L]

require_once('/path/to/wp-config.php');
require_once('/path/to/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
require_once('/path/to/wp-includes/pluggable.php');

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    // redirect to login page or show the message + login form
    die; // or exit, wp_redirect etc
}

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"] .".pdf";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp); ```


All pdfs urls are public accessible
https://abc/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/2019/05/Testing-pdf-1.pdf
````

Comment: did you restart apache?

Comment: Yes, and i'm using aws server

Comment: try using .htaccess . here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728976/how-to-deny-access-to-a-file-in-htaccess

Comment: I'm using apache 2.4.33
is there any problem because of the version ?

Comment: Should not have issues due to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in the .htaccess file to block directory access from URL.

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here. One of our main goals is to configure Bitnami applications in the most secure way. For this reason, we moved the configuration in the .htaccess files to the main application configuration files and set the AllowOverride option to None by default.

The content of the .htaccess files have been moved to the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf file. If you want to add new information, please follow these steps

- Add a new entry in the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf file specifying the path where the htaccess file is (/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs) and pasting below the content of that file.

> NOTE: CONTENT OF THE .htaccess FILE HERE is a placeholder, replace it with the content of the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/.htaccess file created by the plugin.

```
...
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs">
CONTENT OF THE .htaccess FILE HERE
</Directory>
```

- Restart Apache to make the changes take effect:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```

You can find more information in our documentation: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-htaccess/